# Matplotlib Contour Python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a small problem with `matplotlib` in Python.

I try to create a 2D Map with 3 coordinates (x,y,z)

But only a few part of my points are in the contours :

[image: Plot image]

This is my code :

```
def grid(x, y, z, resX=500, resY=500):
  xi = np.linspace(min(x), max(x), resX)
  yi = np.linspace(min(y), max(y), resY)
  Z = ml.griddata(x, y, z, xi, yi)
  X, Y = np.meshgrid(xi, yi)
  return X, Y, Z

x = [5,10,15,40]
 ...

X,Y,Z = grid(x,y,z)
plt.contour(X,Y,Z)
```

Comment: can you show the code for y,z too? try specifying the number of regions to use with contour. eg:
plt.contour(X,Y,Z,5)

Comment: I have a huge amount of coordinates for x, y and z. Dimension of my tab is 2000. Maybe it doesn't work for too much data ? I have also removes every eventual duplicates from my list ...

Comment: I've also tried your proposition and it's not working ...

Comment: I have found a semi solution. I use :
rbf = scipy.interpolate.Rbf(x, y, z, function='linear') and it works....

Comment: ah right, so it must have been the griddata not working as intended